# AWS SSM CRON ISSUE - InvalidSchedule: Schedule expression cron(0 11 ? * MON-FRI *) is currently not accepted

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-ssm

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a state manager association using cron:

```
 InvalidSchedule: Schedule expression cron(0 11 ? * MON-FRI *) is currently not accepted. Supported expressions are every half, 1, 2, 4, 8 or 12 hour(s), every specified day and time of the week. Supported examples are: cron(0 0/30 * 1/1 * ? *), cron(0 0 0/4 1/1 * ? *), cron (0 0 10 ? * SUN *), cron (0 0 10 ? * * *)
```

The cron syntax that I'm using is the following:

```
cron(0 11 ? * MON-FRI *)
```

According to the documentation the cron syntax is correct:
**Cron expression examples**

```
6:00 PM Monday through Friday

cron(0 18 ? * MON-FRI *)
```

Any thought about it? Maybe SSM is not allowed to execute cron job with more than one day on the syntax

Comment: It's not that the cron expression is invalid, it's that those associations have limited flexibility in the schedules they allow. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/reference-cron-and-rate-expressions.html#reference-cron-and-rate-expressions-association

Comment: thanks for the answer, I appreciate it